# How to registerTempTable in SparkSQL

Tags: apache-spark-sql

Spark version:2.2.0.cloudera2

Usually, we register a temp table in this way:

`dataframe.registerTempTable($table_name)`

But if I want to create a table in SQL statement, like this:

`CREATE TABLE test_table from select * from table1`

Spark will create a permanent table. Is there some way to create a temp table in SparkSQL statement?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add TEMPORARY keyword in the SQL statement which would restrict writing the records to hive metastore for that particular table.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test_table from select * from table1
```

Refer: https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/create-table.html

Comment: Many thanks! This document seems to have more example rather than official website. My spark version need to use `CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW`, and solve my question.